# How Struts 2 handle request parameters

Tags: struts2

I remember I've read this from somewhere but still unsure.

consider scenario below:

```
<action name="doSomething" class="com.domain.MyAction" method="myMethod">              
    </action>
```

and

```
 public class MyAction extends ActionSupport{

      public String myMethod(){
       private String param;

       }
       //getter
       //setter
    }
```

then via web page I do `POST o GET: domain/doSomething?param=hello`

I can recover "param" value using any method below, are they the same?

```
this.getParam();
(String)request.getParameter("param");
(String)request.getSession.getAttribute("param");
```

if so, then struts will always put request parameters into http_session?

Comment: No, S2 doesn't put anything into the session unless you tell it to.

Comment: The variable & its getter/setter methods must be declared outside the `myMethod()` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Struts uses getters and setters of request parameters to pass them in the action.

```
 public class MyAction extends ActionSupport{

   private String param;
   public void setParam(String p){ param=p;  }
   public String getParam() { return param; }

  public String myMethod(){
      System.out.println("Got the request parameter automatically just by having a getter and setter for that parameter " + param);
   }
}
```